# Duplicated-entry validation in EF and "entity being already tracked" error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core, validation

Please assist me on beginner's path, I'm trying to set up a duplicate-entry validation on my Customer class, filtering 'email' or 'name' values.
The validation filter works, new entries are being saved, however when editing, I can't update the entity and keep getting error on db.Update():

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The instance of entity type 'Customer' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'CustomerID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.

Though the message looks self-explaining, I can't figure out what to change to make code properly working preserving duplicate-entry validation.

My actions are:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
 {
     var editedCustomer = _unitOfWork.Customer.Get(c => c.CustomerID == id);
     CustomerViewModel customerVM = new()
     {
         Customer = editedCustomer
     };
     return View(customerVM);
 }
```

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Edit(CustomerViewModel editedCustomerVM)
 {            
     var result =  _unitOfWork.Customer.GetAll()
         .Where(c => c.CustomerID != editedCustomerVM.Customer.CustomerID)
         .Where(c => c.CustomerEmail == editedCustomerVM.Customer.CustomerEmail)
         .Any();

  if (result)
     {
        var objVM = ReCreateGetView(editedCustomerVM.Customer);
        CreateCustomerAlert(objVM, "Possible duplicated entry existing!");
    return View(objVM);
     }

     _unitOfWork.Customer.Update(editedCustomerVM.Customer);
   ...
   ...
```

Tried to materialize "result" and its elements to move data from query to memory on various ways, but it didn't help at all. Removing of '_unitOfWork' call in Post method helps, but it obviously also excludes expected anti-duplicate validiation.

Comment: What is `_unitOfWork`?  And how do you manage its lifetime?

Comment: @David Browne It is my unit of work of repository pattern and it is registered with scoped lifetime. In a meanwhile I changed my "result" query into: 'var result = _unitOfWork.Customer.Any(c => c.CustomerID != editedCustomer.Customer.CustomerID && c.CustomerName == editedCustomer.Customer.CustomerName);' and it solved the problem. It works properly now, I would just love to know, what exactly was causing double tracking of the same instance? Was it filtering whole "Customer" objects collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is caused when you try and use `Update` on an instance of an entity that the DbContext has already loaded and is tracking.

```
 var result =  _unitOfWork.Customer.GetAll()
     .Where(c => c.CustomerID != editedCustomerVM.Customer.CustomerID)
     .Where(c => c.CustomerEmail == editedCustomerVM.Customer.CustomerEmail)
     .Any();
```

Chances are your "GetAll()" method above is returning a materialized list of all customers rather than an `IQueryable<Customer>()`. This is expensive, and is completely unnecessary as the EF DbContext already operates as a unit of work.

As a general rule I recommend avoiding passing Entities between controllers and views. Entities represent data state, view models represent view state. The EditedCustomerViewModel should contain the values that you allow to be edited, and only the values that can be updated. Accepting a Customer as part of the view model and calling `Update()` looks like a simple and convenient way of updating data, but it is dangerous in the sense that it can allow data you don't intend to change to be changed, and it also runs foul as soon as you start introducing navigation properties and the like.

Instead, consider tracking and providing the modified fields in the view model, then the update looks more like:

```
[HttpPost]
 public IActionResult Edit(CustomerViewModel editedCustomerVM)
 {            
     var duplicateEmailAddress = _context.Customers
          .Where(c => c.CustomerID != editedCustomerVm.CustomerID
              && c.EmailAddress == editedCustomerVm.EmailAddress)
          .Any();
     if(duplicateEmailAddress)
     {
         string validationMessage = "Another employee exists for the same Email address.";
         return RedirectToAction("Edit", new {EmployeeID = editedCustomerVM.EmployeeID, validationMessage});
     } 

     var customer =  _context.Customers.Single(c => c.CustomerID == editedCustomerVM.CustomerID);

     // Copy allowed values from the view model into the entity.
     customer.UpdateableValue = editedCustomerVM.UpdatedValue;

     _context.SaveChanges();

     return View(new { CustomerID = editedCustomerVM.CustomerID })
}
```

The main details here: When going to the DbContext to check for a duplicate Email address we want to ensure that we aren't loading any entities into the tracking cache. I suspect the UoW wrapper you have is materializing entities which will be problematic, and wasteful in terms of performance.

If we validate and look for a duplicate Email address, return a RedirectResponse and pass the message as part of that response. The Edit view can look for a validationMessage and display something like a Toastr alert or what-have-you for the user. Now in this example all changes are discarded so the Edit view would reload all data. Alternatively you could continue to copy data across from the VM to the entity, except the Email address, save those changes, then return to the edit page with the validation warning.

When it comes to updating the entity, we load the entity from the DbContext then copy the allowed values across before calling SaveChanges rather than using the `Update()` method. `Update()` works with detached entities, but only so long as you ensure the DbContext isn't already tracking an entity. I do not recommend this approach for updating data because even in the best case where you are sure there are no tracking references to screw things up, `Update` will generate an SQL UPDATE statement for all fields in the table whether anything was changed or not. Using the EF change tracker instead, any UPDATE statement will only include values that actually changed, and the UPDATE statement will only be created if anything actually does change.

Comment: Wow, thanks for great explanation. Yes, my GetAll() is returning ToList(). 

I've read about EF vs. Unit of Work concerns but couldn't recognize by myself what approach is better or more propper. UoW seemed to be convenient and quite often implemented solution, also most (of the one I found) tutorials were based on UoW. I'm very keen to reconsider and refactor my code now. I still lack knowledge about where and when exactly tracking begins but will definitely dig for more info. Thanks for your support!